# Is there a way to use aggregate COUNT() values within CASE?

Tags: mysql, count, case

I need to retrieve unique yet truncated part numbers, with their description values being conditionally determined.

**DATA:**
Here's some simplified sample data:
(the real table has half a million rows)

```
create table inventory(
   partnumber VARCHAR(10),
   description VARCHAR(10)
);
INSERT INTO inventory (partnumber,description) VALUES
    ('12345','ABCDE'),
    ('123456','ABCDEF'),
    ('1234567','ABCDEFG'),
    ('98765','ZYXWV'),
    ('987654','ZYXWVU'),
    ('9876543','ZYXWVUT'),
    ('abcde',''),
    ('abcdef','123'),
    ('abcdefg','321'),
    ('zyxwv',NULL),
    ('zyxwvu','987'),
    ('zyxwvut','789');
```

**TRIED:**
I've tried too many things to list here.
I've [finally found a way](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ec2134/9) to get past all the 'unknown field' errors and at least get *SOME* results, but:

1. it's *SUPER* kludgy!
2. my results are not limited to unique `prod`s.

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT
  LEFT(i.partnumber, 6) AS prod,
  CASE
    WHEN agg.cnt > 1
    OR i.description IS NULL
    OR i.description = ''
    THEN LEFT(i.partnumber, 6)
    ELSE i.description
  END AS `descrip`
  FROM inventory i
  INNER JOIN (SELECT LEFT(ii.partnumber, 6) t, COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM inventory ii GROUP BY ii.partnumber) AS agg
  ON LEFT(i.partnumber, 6) = agg.t;
```

**GOAL:**
My goal is to retrieve:

| prod | descrip |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | ABCDE |
| 123456 | 123456 |
| 98765 | ZYXWV |
| 987654 | 987654 |
| abcde | abcde |
| abcdef | abcdef |
| zyxwv | zyxwv |
| zyxwvu | zyxwvu |

**QUESTION:**

1. What are some cleaner ways to use the `COUNT()` aggregate data with a `CASE` type conditional?
2. How can I limit my results so that all `prod`s are UNIQUE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a `left(partnumber, 6)` is not unique in the result by checking if `count(*) > 1`. In such a case let `descrip` be `left(partnumber, 6)`. Otherwise you can use `max(description)` (or `min(description)`) to get the *single* description but satisfy the needs to use an aggregation function on columns not in the `GROUP BY`. To replace empty or `NULL` descriptions, `nullif()` and `coalesce()` can be used.

That would lead to the following using just one level of aggregation and no joins:

```
SELECT left(partnumber, 6) AS prod,
       CASE
         WHEN count(*) > 1 THEN
           left(partnumber, 6)
         ELSE
           coalesce(nullif(max(description), ''), left(partnumber, 6))
       END AS descrip
       FROM inventory
       GROUP BY left(partnumber, 6)
       ORDER BY left(partnumber, 6);
```

But there seems to be a bug in MySQL and this query fails. The engine doesn't "see" that, in the list after `SELECT` `partnumber` is only used in the expression `left(partnumber, 6)`, which is also in the `GROUP BY`. Instead the engine falsely complains about `partnumber` not being in the `GROUP BY` and not subject to an aggregation function.

As a workaround, we can use a derived table, that does the shortening of `partnumber` to its first six characters. We then use use that column of the derived table instead of `left(partnumber, 6)`.

```
SELECT l6pn AS prod,
       CASE
         WHEN count(*) > 1 THEN
           l6pn
         ELSE
           coalesce(nullif(max(description), ''), l6pn)
       END AS descrip
       FROM (SELECT left(partnumber, 6) AS l6pn,
                    description
                    FROM inventory) AS x
       GROUP BY l6pn
       ORDER BY l6pn;
```

Or we slap some actually pointless `max()`es around the `left(partnumber, 6)` other than the first, to work around the bug.

```
SELECT left(partnumber, 6) AS prod,
       CASE
         WHEN count(*) > 1 THEN
           max(left(partnumber, 6))
         ELSE
           coalesce(nullif(max(description), ''), max(left(partnumber, 6)))
       END AS descrip
       FROM inventory
       GROUP BY left(partnumber, 6)
       ORDER BY left(partnumber, 6);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=091cfea66a1757af42b5830759fbe220) (Change the DBMS to some other like Postgres or MariaDB to see that they also accept the first query.)

Comment: SOOO helpful! Thanks-a-bunch for such a complete description. Took me a while to wrap my head around, but _immensely_ helpful! Thank you